# Google script DocsList service query string not working

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm making a little script to automatically organize some autogenerated spreadsheets. The goal is to archive the spreadsheets in a directory based on their name (all of them start with the same name but end in a pattern I'm using to organize them). The problem I have is with the function:

```
lstFile = DocsList.find('type:spreadsheet title:"PROG_GRAL_CENTRE"');
```

The function doesn't have the query options specified in [the docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_docslist#find), but I'm using it on another script and is working fine! I've also tried putting only:

```
lstFile = DocsList.find('PROG_GRAL_CENTRE');
```

which should find 200 documents, but none is found! Actually, if I type PROG_GRAL_CENTRE into the search box of my google Drive, all the documents are found, so I don't know what's wrong with my search filter.

Any thoughts?

Comment: It seems, there is an [opened issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=876&q=DocsList.find&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner) which may be related... I'm following it right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method find(query) looks for a string in file content, not only on file name... so even it it worked normally (meaning without the issue you mentioned) I'm not sure it would be a good solution for your use case since there would be a risk that some filename could be found inside another doc with another name (as a reference for example...).

Why don't you try getting all filenames in an array and search into this array instead ? 
This can be done very easily and would bring an elegant solution to your problem wouldn't it ?

I'm working on this very same type of script right now ;-) here is the part that gets my files  (just an example if ever you are interested):

```
var doclist=DocsList.getRootFolder().getFilesByType("document",0,2000);
var names = new Array();
  for (nn=0;nn<doclist.length;++nn){
    if(doclist[nn].getName().match("IMPRESSION_")=="IMPRESSION_"){
  names.push([doclist[nn].getName(),doclist[nn].getId()]);
  }
  }
```

after that I sort the array the way I want and show the result in a list UI.

Comment: Mmm, sounds promising. I'll try it later and give some feed back.

Comment: Ok, Sorry for resurrecting the "dead", but I've finally got some time to work more on this. I've found [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1127) to be a very valuable point of information. See [this comment](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1127#c6), it's comment #6. BTW, I ended up merging your suggestion and some code from the getFileByName function. Thanks!

Comment: funny, I just finalise a new version of my doclist UI app with a search yesterday... if you want to [have a look ;-)](https://sites.google.com/site/appsscriptexperiments/home/doclist-viewer-new-version). Thanks for the info & links. You could publish your final code maybe ? I'm always interested ;-)